# Gesture Recognizer on sub-view outside view's bounds

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I have a view that is able to be dragged around the screen via pan gestures.  Once the view is selected, little grippers appear on the corners of the view that allow the user to resize the view.  The problem is, those grippers go outside the bounds of the view (they still show up, because clipSubviews is off), but gesture recognizers on those grippers are not firing when selecting the part of them that is drawn outside of the view.  Making the view bigger to actually hold the grippers would break a lot of already created logic that is based on the size of the view, so that is a last resort for me.

Is there any other way to get gesture recognizers to work on views that are drawn outside of their parent view?

Comment: How you obtain that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try overriding [`hitTest:withEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest%3awithEvent%3a) in a UIView subclass, and return the gripper view.

Comment: According to the documentation `Points that lie outside the receiver’s bounds are never reported as hits, even if they actually lie within one of the receiver’s subviews. This can occur if the current view’s clipsToBounds property is set to NO and the affected subview extends beyond the view’s bounds. `  So i'm thinking that won't work.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia That I believe is the default implementation.You'll have to subclass, override and change its behaviour.

Comment: OK I'll give it a try.

Comment: I used point(inside:with:) instead, it's easier and it works too ! Thanks for pointing the right direction !